# How to improve the look/aspect/resolution of a Text Render in my game?

Tags: unreal-4, text

In my game there are warriors who walk the map following a path. Above their heads is shown their life (text render).

It turns out that unlike when I'm simulating the game (I'm not possessing the character) the visualization of the warriors life is practically impossible.

**Image of when the warrior and my character are walking:**

[image]

**Even with my character stopped the visualization of life is horrible:**

[image]

**I have not changed much since the creation of the Text Render, but if it helps:**

[image]

I want the improvement to be simply in the sense that I can easily identify the value of the warrior's life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because of the motion blur effect, you can either try to disable it in the rendering section of the project settings, or you can use [2D UI](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/UMG/HowTo/CreatingWidgets/index.html) instead of the current approach involving real 3D geometry in your game world.

Answer (score 0):

Just to supplement the information on my problem and show a possible solution for anyone who has the same problem..

**I discovered today that this blurring is largely due to the fact that I defined the value of the Text Render at all times (Event Tick):**

[image]

I discovered that was the main cause of the problem when using this same code in my character.

It was not as bad as the warriors, but it was very out of focus.

I opted for the definition of the Text Render so that the display of the warrior's life (and later the character) is as accurate as possible, however, it gives equal (or near) precision when defining the Text Render only when there is a change in value.

**Examples of when to set the Text Render:**

- character/warrior raise the level (with that his maximum life increased)
- character/warrior received damage

From these events is just call an event that updates the Text Render, or even the very action of losing life. The mode is at the discretion of each one.